# JobRunShell.cs not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, quartz-scheduler

I'm using Quartz.Net to schedule Jobs. Please see my code . Why does this error occur?

I need to register the data in the database.

error :
[image]

I'm using this code to register data :

```
public class NewsSchedule : INewsSchedule
{
    public void Run(int minute)
    {
        DateTimeOffset startTime = DateBuilder.FutureDate(2, IntervalUnit.Second);

        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<NewsJob>()
                                   .WithIdentity("newsJob")
                                   .Build();

        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                                         .WithIdentity("trigger1")
                                         .StartAt(startTime)
                                         .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInSeconds(60).RepeatForever())
                                         .Build();

        ISchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        IScheduler sc = sf.GetScheduler();
        sc.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);

        sc.Start();
    }
}
public interface INewsSchedule
{
    void Run(int minute);
}
public class NewsJob : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=NewsApk;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
        sqlConnection.Open();
        var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("Insert into JN_NewsCategories(NewsCategoriesFr,NewsCategoriesEn,IsGetNews)Values(@1,@2,@3)");
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", "test");
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", "test2");
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@3", false);
        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

**Update :**

Please see :

The Select command works correctly, but the register Command does not work.

```
public class NewsJob : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        var sqlConnection =
            new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=NewsApk;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
        sqlConnection.Open();
        var sqlCommand =
            new SqlCommand(
                "Insert into JN_NewsCategories(NewsCategoriesFa,NewsCategoriesEn,IsGetNews)Values(@1,@2,@3)");
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", "test");
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", "test2");
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@3", false);

        SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from JN_NewsCategories", sqlConnection);
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);// 12 record found. its ok.

        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        sqlConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

thanks @K.B. i found error. "Message = "ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.". Why does this error occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found answer.

replace this :

```
 var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("Insert into JN_NewsCategories(NewsCategoriesFa,NewsCategoriesEn,IsGetNews)Values(@1,@2,@3)");
```

with this :

```
 var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("Insert into JN_NewsCategories(NewsCategoriesFa,NewsCategoriesEn,IsGetNews)Values(@1,@2,@3)",sqlConnection);
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue was due to your database connection or something related to database,
Nothing to do with Quartz.

Answer (score 0):

this not an issue it's telling  that he cannot find  the pdb for Quartz to overcome this you have 2 Choices:

1. Download the source code of project  and reference it
2. or from the menu ->tools -> options ->debugging-> general and be sure that you have checked the Enable Just My Code

[image]

Comment: I have checked the Enable Just My Code . There was no difference.

Comment: thanks. i found error. "Message = "ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.". Why does this error occur?